# How to set an HTML attribute based in screen size? I need to change mat-progress-spinner diameter based on screen size

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm not able to set an attribute based on the screen size

This is my code:

The "(screen.width < 1024)? 60 : 100" condition is not working.
I have also tried
$('#matspin').setAttribute('diameter','60'); inside windows.load and document.ready
that is not working too.

Appreciate your help ppls

Answer (score 1):

Generally this makes using [media query breakpoints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

In "styles.css" -should be in a global-styles-

```
/*Begin with the min-width of your spinner*/
.p-progress-spinner.custom-spinner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
/*when "screen.width">=300px */
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .p-progress-spinner.custom-spinner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
/*when "screen.width">=500px */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .p-progress-spinner.custom-spinner {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}
...
```

The "typical" break points are, using bootstrap [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints), using tailwinds [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens), but you can create your owns breakpoints as several designers suggest

NOTE: You're using Angular, mixing Angular and jQuery it's not recomended (and it's always unnecessary -really jQuery should be unnecessary at all-)